# Beamer presentation not splitting frames properly on contents page

Tags: beamer, presentations, slideshow

I'm working on a presentation on `beamer`, however my table of contents is slightly too large for one slide, I have tried including allowframebreaks in, however this just pushes it to the next slide without centering it. Does anyone know how I can sort this? I have seen loads of other answers to this but none seemed to work for me, I am very new to beamer so might just be making a silly mistake. Thanks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} % new 
\begin{document}
\title{A history of Ordinary differential equations and their applications within Biology, Physics and the economy} 
\author{Tarran Dutton} 
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 
\frame[allowframebreaks]%
{\frametitle{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents}







\section{1 - An introduction into Ordinary differential equations} 
\frame{\frametitle{1 - An introduction into Ordinary differential equations} 

}
\subsection{- A Background on ODE's}
\subsection{- What is an Ordinary differential equation?}
\frame{ 

}


\section{2 - History of ODE's} 
\subsection{- Origins of ODE's}
\frame{\frametitle{- Origins of ODE's}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
}

\frame{\frametitle{lists with pause}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
}

\subsection{- The minds that helped}
\frame{\frametitle{- The minds that helped}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}
\frame{\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}

\section{3 - Applications within Biology} 
\subsection{- Population growth}
\frame{\frametitle{Population growth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
}

\frame{\frametitle{lists with pause}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
}

\subsection{- Disease spread}
\frame{\frametitle{Disease spread}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}
\frame{\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
}






\section{4 - Applications within Physics}
\subsection{- Nuclear Decay}
\frame{\frametitle{Nuclear Decay}
}
\subsection{- Atmospheric pressure}
\frame{\frametitle{Atmospheric pressure}
}

\section{5 - Applications within the Econonmy}

\subsection{- The Solow Swan Method}
\frame{\frametitle{The Solow Swan Method}
}
\subsection{- The Sethi Model}
\frame{\frametitle{The Sethi Model}
}

\section{6 - Conclusion}
\frame{\frametitle{Conclusion}

}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the break manually, you have much more control:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 

\title[History and application of ODE]{A history of Ordinary differential equations and their applications within Biology, Physics and the economy} 
\author{Tarran Dutton} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[sections=1-3]
        \framebreak
        \tableofcontents[sections=4-6]
    \end{frame} 

    \section{1 - An introduction into Ordinary differential equations} 
    \frame{\frametitle{1 - An introduction into Ordinary differential equations}}

    \subsection{- A Background on ODE's}
    \subsection{- What is an Ordinary differential equation?}
    \frame{}


    \section{2 - History of ODE's} 
    \subsection{- Origins of ODE's}
    \frame{\frametitle{- Origins of ODE's}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
            \item Course 2 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{itemize} 
    }

    \frame{\frametitle{lists with pause}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Course 2 \pause 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{itemize} 
    }

    \subsection{- The minds that helped}
    \frame{\frametitle{- The minds that helped}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
            \item Course 2 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \frame{\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Course 2 \pause 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{enumerate}
    }

    \section{3 - Applications within Biology} 
    \subsection{- Population growth}
    \frame{\frametitle{Population growth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
            \item Course 2 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{itemize} 
    }

    \frame{\frametitle{lists with pause}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Course 2 \pause 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{itemize} 
    }

    \subsection{- Disease spread}
    \frame{\frametitle{Disease spread}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
            \item Course 2 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \frame{\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Course 2 \pause 
            \item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
            \item Beamer class
        \end{enumerate}
    }

    \section{4 - Applications within Physics}
    \subsection{- Nuclear Decay}
    \frame{\frametitle{Nuclear Decay}   }
    \subsection{- Atmospheric pressure}
    \frame{\frametitle{Atmospheric pressure}    }

    \section{5 - Applications within the Econonmy}

    \subsection{- The Solow Swan Method}
    \frame{\frametitle{The Solow Swan Method}}
    \subsection{- The Sethi Model}
    \frame{\frametitle{The Sethi Model}}

    \section{6 - Conclusion}
    \frame{\frametitle{Conclusion}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As the navigation bar is redundant to the table of contents, you might want to remove it:

```
\begingroup
    \makeatletter 
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default] 
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[sections=1-3]
        \framebreak
        \tableofcontents[sections=4-6]
    \end{frame} 
\endgroup
```

Comment: @Tarran You're welcome! BTW: your title is too long for your footline. See my edited answer for an alternative.